# bottom div overlap with fixed dynamic div

Tags: html, css

I know it might sound like a familiar problem but I am unable to solve it. I have two `div`s one  is fixed and other is not. The problem is the `height` of fixed div is not known as it is populated at run time. So I can't give any value in the `top` property of the second `div`. I looked a lot of examples but in most of examples the `height` is fixed which is not in my case.

Here is my code:

```
 <div>
        <div style='position:fixed;width:100%;z-index: 10000; top: 0; '>
            <div id="main"></div>
        </div> 
        <div id='jsGrid' style='z-index: 10030;top:130px'></div>


    </div>
```

As you can see in image, the table is overlapping with the fixed `div`.
[image]

Here is the link to Jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/maqsoodgul/s1hjy147/

Comment: Put this in a jsFiddle for us

Comment: @davvv link added